# Mark only event's start date and end date in event calender

Tags: javascript

I want to mark only the start date and end date in the event calendar. For example, if the event starts from 5th of a month and ends on 17th of the same month. I need to show the text *event1 opening* on 5th  and *event1 closing* on the 17th.

[image: screenshot]

An event calendar is instead shown as follows.

[image]

I'm using FullCalendar for this.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [FullCalendar](https://drupal.org/project/fullcalendar) to dispaly the calendar, you need to register two separate events:

1. Exhibit opening: Wild & Wonderful (starts end ends on the 5th).
2. Exhibit closing: Wild & Wonderful (starts end ends on the 17th).

Now, the opening and closing event will appear independent of each other,